# Finding users missing licenses

Tags: powershell

While looking into my allocated licenses I found a discrepancy. All of my users that have the license with the SKU "M365EDU_A3_FACULTY" should also have the license "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY" but i'm seeing a difference of 19 in these licenses.

In order to find these differences without sorting through the 1300 accounts manually I created the following command with some help of online resources.

```
get-msoluser -all | where {$_.isLicensed -eq "M365EDU_A3_FACULTY"} | ?{get-msoluser -all | where {$_.isLicensed -eq "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY"} -NotContains $_}
```

So far this command has taken up a rather large portion of my time in its execution and the results im getting are users that are not supposed to have either of those licenses.

After some digging i found that the command functions better as follows

```
Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "M365EDU_A3_FACULTY"} | ?{Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY"} -NotContains $_}
```

The problem is it's still taking forever to run. is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: `isLicensed` is a boolean property, either `$true` or `$false`. Are you sure you didn't mean `{ $_.Licenses ... }` ?

Comment: I was able to find a little more about this, but you're right.
I'll add to the original post what i've found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is quite slow because you're querying **all users** as many times as users exist with a **`IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY`** license.

All users returned from this expression:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -match ... } | ...
```

Are being piped to a new `Where-Object`, and, for each object from pipeline, you're querying **all users over and over**:

```
... | Where-Object { Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object ... }
```

---

Below code could be improved if `Get-MsolUser` had a built-in filter, unfortunately, that's not the case. Try this one out, it should return those users which **have the `M365EDU_A3_FACULTY` license** but **do not have the `IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY` license**.

```
$license1 = "M365EDU_A3_FACULTY"
$license2 = "IDENTITY_THREAT_PROTECTION_FACULTY"

$result = foreach($user in Get-MsolUser -All) {
    $licenses = $user.Licenses.AccountSkuId
    if($licenses -contains $license1 -and $licenses -notcontains $license2) {
        $user
    }
}

$result | Format-Table
```

Comment: It's a pity there is nothing beyond a green checkmark to express gratitude. It ran way faster than my current command.

Comment: It was my pleasure @NorwegiaMan, glad it worked well